# Javascript: Insert new rows into table by checking row top position

Tags: javascript, css-position

I want to insert two new rows when a row's top position exceeds a limit in pixel.
I've tried following code but its not working properly.
**I'm adding these two rows for page break and repeating table header purpose.**
   Following is the print preview of this code ran:
[image]
The header should repeat at next page only.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');  
var rowTopVal = 0;  
var tIndex = 0;  
var deductVal = 0;  
var tableId = document.getElementById("testID");  

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {  
  rowTopVal = x[i].position().top;  
  rowTopVal = rowTopVal - deductVal;  

  if (1200 < rowTopVal) {  
    tIndex = i;  
    var row = tableId.insertRow(tIndex);  

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);  
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);  
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);  
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);  

    cell1.innerHTML = "x";  
    cell2.innerHTML = "Y";  
    cell3.innerHTML = "z";  
    cell4.innerHTML = "P";  
    cell5.innerHTML = "q";  

    row.className = 'tableHeaderRepeat';  
    var row2 = tableId.insertRow(tIndex);  
    row2.className = 'tableHeaderRepeatBlank';  
    newRow1Height = parseInt($('.tableHeaderRepeatBlank').css('height'), 10);  
    newRow2Height = parseInt($('.tableHeaderRepeat').css('height'), 10);    
    deductVal = deductVal + rowTopVal - newRow1Height - newRow2Height;  
  }  
}
```

Comment: If possible please prepare jsfiddle for this.

Comment: `Y"` and `"z` need to be quoted properly. Is that error in your live code?

Comment: No. I've just replaced values with actual values.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle. I.g. on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I can not create jsfiddle for this because front end code written with another language. Consider this problem with regards to html only.

Comment: What my logic is check top position of each row of table, if it exceeds more than a size of A4 size paper, then it should break for next page and header should repeated. Page break will be added by inserting a row with height and left, right border 0px and next row work as header.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try adding css property to your table headers? See [CSS page break properties](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/).
Example:

```
.tableHeaderRepeat { page-break-before: always; }
```

It should add a page break before every table header, so you only need to approximately calculate the position to start a new table. I'm not able to test this right now, but maybe it'll help.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not works for Chrome that's why this short term fix is going on.. Ref: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that, sorry. But when I look at the dates out there and see that it was first mentioned nearly 5 years ago - I don't think it'll be a `short term` fix, so good luck :)

Comment: Chrome did not solve this problem of table header repeating  yet, so some solution need to be invent.. ;)